# mysql insert concatenate a constant value

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a constant called TUC and concatenate it with the initials of FirstName and LastName id of table.

id -   1 
fname -  James 
lname -  Bond

id -   2 
fname -  Daniel 
lname -  Edgar

eg. TUCJB001, TUCDE002,....

Comment: do you have this data before? If not, please handle this at programming end

Comment: check my answer. Its working (ir-respective of length of id). I have provided link too for checking purpose. I have also added 2 & 3 digit number for your testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this

```
update tab 
SET newid=CONCAT('TUC', LEFT(fname, 1), LEFT(lname, 1), LPAD(id,03, '0'));
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0127/1)

Note If you want 4 digit number you will need do changes as highlighted below.

```
update tab 
SET newid=CONCAT('TUC', LEFT(fname, 1), LEFT(lname, 1), LPAD(id,digit_range, '0'));
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to get the value:

```
select 
  concat('TUC', left(firstname, 1), left(lastname, 1), '00', cast(id as char)) newValue
from yourtable
```

Then to update:

```
update yourtable
set yourColumn =  concat('TUC', left(firstname, 1), left(lastname, 1), '00', cast(id as char))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b5ea/14)

Comment: You need to use `LPAD` on the ID instead of just concatenating the `'00'`, or else you'll end up with `00187`. Unless, of course, you're only planning on having 9 of them.

Comment: @General_Mayhem the OP's requirements are not fully clear as to what they want but if needed, then `LPAD` can be used

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE [table] SET [columnname] = CONCAT( UPPER(LEFT(fname, 1)), UPPER(LEFT(lname, 1)), LPAD(CONVERT(id, VARCHAR), 3, '0') );`